# AngularJS Material Design in Eclipse

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, angularjs-material

Is there any reason why Eclipse doesn't see directives from https://material.angularjs.org/latest/?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "doesn't see" mean?

Comment: sorry, I was referring to the autocomplete which works for ng directives but not for md.